# python script path compute engine for cloud composer bashoperator

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-composer

I am working on GCP for the first time and I am trying to execute python script on compute engine using bashoperator. I stored my python script in bucket where composer script is located, but when I try to run the bashoperator it throws an error file not found. can I know where should I place my python script so that I can execute that python script on compute engine.

`

```
 bash_task = bash_operator.BashOperator(
    task_id='script_execution',
    bash_command='gcloud compute ssh --project '+PROJECT_ID+ ' --zone '+REGION+' '+GCE_INSTANCE+ '--command python3 script.py',
    dag=dag)
```

python3: can't open file '/home/airflow/gcs/dags/script.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: Why you don’t run your Python script directly in Composer nodes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Solution 1:

Instead of executing a `Python` script in a separated `Compute Engine` VM instance from `Cloud Composer`, you can directly execute a Python code in Composer with `PythonOperator` :

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

def my_func(*op_args):
   print(op_args)
   # your Python script and logic here 

with DAG('python_dag', description='Python DAG', schedule_interval='*/5 * * * *', start_date=datetime(2018, 11, 1), catchup=False) as dag:
   dummy_task = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy_task', retries=3)
   python_task = PythonOperator(task_id='python_task', python_callable=my_func, op_args=['one', 'two', 'three'])

dummy_task >> python_task
```

- Solution 2 :

Use SSHOperator in Cloud Composer, this topic can help :

[ssh launch script VM Composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58444956/how-we-can-execute-bash-script-which-present-in-compute-engine-vm-from-gcp-com?rq=1)

In this case the script is located in the VM.

- Solution 3 :

You can also think about to rewrite your Python script in Beam and Dataflow Python, if it’s no so complicated to rewrite it.
Dataflow has the advantage to be serverless and Airflow proposes built in operators to launch Dataflow jobs.

Comment: Thanks for response @mazlum. the reason I am using compute engine is because the script I am executing needs 128 cpu and 512gb ram, so we use high end compute engine( even with this compute engine it takes 3hrs to run the script)

Comment: Ok I am going to edit my answer

Comment: I edited my answer with other propositions. For example you can try `SSHOperator`